# Can I change delay on mouse over action in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, mouse

when you point your mouse over a taskbar pinned icon - there is some action happens - in Windows 7 you can see the windows opened (if its running) or there is a tooltip with the program name (if its not running).

There is considerable delay for the tooltip and very short delay for list of running instances.

**Can I change the delay to open the list of the program running instances ?**

Comment: fine. thanks. but the guy who wrote the correct answer was much better than a hop through few links and scrolling few pages of blabbery with pictures... the answer is one line.. I would love to have that guy to write it as an answer and mark it..